# Converting code from Rxjs to xstream

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, cyclejs, xstream-js

What will be the equivalent of

```
return Rx.Observable.merge([deleteTodo$, addTodo$, completeTodo$]).startWith([])
  .scan(function (currentTodos, modifier) { return modifier(currentTodos); });
```

the above in `rxjs` in `xstream`?

Answer (score 2):

Should be like this. Initial value included as second argument after a function.

`xs.merge(deleteTodo$, addTodo$, completeTodo$)
  .fold(function (currentTodos, modifier) { return modifier(currentTodos); }, [])`

Comment: i see, im too late